# Malloc, and size on 32 bit machines

Tags: c, memory, allocation

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
    {
        int *p;
        p = (int *)malloc(20);
        printf("%d\n", sizeof(p));
        free(p);
        return 0;
    }
```

On my 64-bit machine, 4 is printed as the size of p. I'm assuming this is because integers take up 4 bytes in memory, and p is an integer pointer. What if I was running a 32-bit machine? Also, what would happen if I replaced 
int *p with double *p 
and
(int *)malloc(20) with (double *)malloc(20)?

Comment: your question is "what is the size of a pointer".  Where the pointer is pointing makes no difference to this; variables have fixed sizes.

Comment: On my 64b Ubuntu, `p` has a size of 8 bytes, ...

Comment: @MattMcNabb Hmm do you mean "*pointer* variables have fixed sizes"?

Comment: @ring0 it is right if its a 32bit system size is 4 for a pointer while 64bit its 8. Here his build must be in 32 bit even though his OS is 64bit. Isn't it?

Comment: @ring0 no, all variables. (They don't change size after being created)

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming wrong.
In `printf("%d\n", sizeof(p));` you are not printing size of `integer`.You are printing here sizeof 'pointer to an integer' which is 4 bytes in your case.Most probably you will get same result on 32-bit machine.

Now about `malloc`, It allocates number of `bytes` and returns pointer to it.So same size of memory will be allocated even if you cast the pointer from `int*` to `double*`.

Comment: .. and `sizeof` will not tell you how many bytes were allocated in either case

Answer (score 0):

In pointers, It will take four bytes for all pointers.

So while you are checking with `sizeof`, even it is a character pointer it will give four bytes. If you need the value of that pointer use like this.

```
  printf("%d\n", sizeof(p));// It will give the pointer size.
```

`malloc` is allocating the given bytes. And it will give equal to all the pointers. Then don't cast the result of `malloc`. Refer this [link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858)

Comment: can you explain what you mean by "total size of that pointer"?

Answer (score 0):

Irrespective of whether 64-bit system or 32-bit system, size of a pointer variable is 4 bytes by default since 64-bit build settings also have Debug32 by default.
If we specifically change build settings on 64-bit, then the pointer variable can hold 8 bytes.
    I'm assuming this is because integers take up 4 bytes in memory, and p is an integer pointer.

Your assumption is not correct ! To answer your doubt not only integer pointer take up 4 bytes.

int *ptrint;
char *ptrchar; 
float *ptrfloat; 
double *ptrdouble;

Here all ptrint, ptrchar, ptrfloat, ptrdouble takes 4 bytes of memory since it would be the address stored in that variable.

And if you replace int *p with double *p and (int *)malloc(20) with (double *)malloc(20) , the size would be still 4 bytes. I hope this ans cleared your doubts.

Comment: In a 64-bit machine, generally all compilers and default build settings would be 32. Hence pointer variable size would be 4 bytes in general.

Comment: _Irrespective of whether 64-bit system or 32-bit system, size of a pointer variable is 4 bytes._ then obviously its not 'Irrespective', only if you have the wrong build settings...

Answer (score 0):

You have some misunderstanding let me point them,

```
p = (int *)malloc(20);
```

You are allocating memory of 20 bytes and `malloc` returns a void pointer and but compiler does the casting for you and (int *) is not needed. Even though you have a pointer to a `double` or an `int` it takes the same amount of bytes (In a 32bit system this merely for mapping 4GB memory space).

```
// Should this be 4 or 8?
printf("%d\n", sizeof(p));
```

This should be 8 on a x64 platform if your executable or the build is x64 only. I assume your build is 32bit and it returns 4.

Above `printf` has a wrong specifier. `sizeof` returns `size_t` and not an `int`. So correct form should be,

```
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(p));
```